# How to title number of days that were weekend days?

Tags: phrase-requests

I am creating a table which shows spending on some kind of service. Price is based on the amount of usual and weekend days during period of usage of the service, and there is different price for usual/weekend days. So now I have a trouble titling column which will show number of days that were weekend.

Is "Weekend days" a right title? There were also proposals to use "Weekends" but then it is ambiguous if 10 in that column means 20 days or 10. Another one was "Peak/Non-peak days" but this seems to have different meaning: "peak day" may be a usual weekday, but i.e. Christmas.

UPDATE:

To clarify, non-working weekdays should **not** be included, so "Non-Business days", "Non-Working days" and similar phrases don't fit.

Comment: *Naming* requests, including for spreadsheet columns, is off-topic here. But why not call it **Sat-Sun** (as opposed to **Mon-Fri**)?

Comment: I believe Phrase choice is not offtopic here. I am not asking to _name_ the column, but to _choose a right phrase_ either from listed in my question or any other if you have any. Though I see that it can be seen as naming too. **Sat-Sun** is a good proposal, thank you, probably it will be the choice if nothing else appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the request for a title and the objection received for it being off-topic, I think your question is really **What is a generic name for a Saturday or a Sunday?** which is an interesting question.

If *weekday* is a single working day, *weekend* seems like an apt name for a single non-working day.

However, the term *weekend* (singular) is defined by [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/weekend) and [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/weekend) as a 2-day period (commonly Saturday and Sunday together), or possibly longer, functionally described as a (short) period of time away from work. One can therefore speak of a 3-day weekend, for example. Also, the specific days comprising a weekend may [vary between countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workweek_and_weekend#Around_the_world), although Saturday-Sunday is common.

Since a weekend is the complement of a working week, natural terms for a single day within a weekend include **non-working day** and **rest day**. @JHCL's suggestion of naming the days (e.g. *Sat-Sun*) also work.

In a chart, the table could be called *Hourly (or daily) Rates*, and the columns headed *Weekdays* and *Weekend(s)* to indicate the portion of the week that those rates apply.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I can answer this directly, but... Non-weekend days are "Business Days," so you could go with "Non-Business Days." Sounds clunky, but that way you pull in holidays as well.

Comment: I need quite opposite, I need only weekend days in that column, weekdays which are holidays doesn't count. I.e. you used service from Monday till Saturday next week, and first week Tuesday was Christmas, weekday column should contain number 10, and weekend column should be 3. I'm sorry if it wasn't clear from the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you organise the headings to be of like kind, you could use “Weekend”, meaning what *type* of day it is.  That is, you could have a group heading “Day Class” or “Day Type” or just “Day”, and other column headings might be “Business”/“Working” and “Christmas” (when there is a 1.5x surcharge).